# Bounding covariance of random variables with point masses at zero using mixing coefficients

Tags: probability-theory, covariance, mixing

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ (defined on the same probability space) both with point masses at zero:

$$\Pr(X = 0) > 0, \qquad \text{and} \qquad \Pr(Y = 0) > 0.$$

If it makes any difference, we can assume they're fully discrete. I'm trying to bound the covariance between $X$ and $Y$ using a mixing coefficient.

A straightforward such bound is:

$$ \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) \leq 4 \alpha(\sigma(X), \sigma(Y)) \|X\|_\infty\|Y\|_\infty,$$

where $\alpha(\sigma(X), \sigma(Y))$ is the $\alpha$-mixing coefficient between the $\sigma$-algebras generated by $X$ and $Y$, and $\|A\|_\infty$ is the essential supremum of $A$. (See, e.g., Lemma 3 on page 10 in Doukhan, 1994).

However, this does not exploit that we know that there are point masses at zero. **Can we use that information to sharpen the bound?**

Doukhan (1994), "Mixing: Properties and Examples." [Paywall link.](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387942148) [Non-paywall link.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243765588_Mixing_Properties_and_Examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a random variable $Z$ and $u\in[0,1]$, define $$Q_Z\left(u\right):=\inf\left\{t \mid \mathbb P\left(\left|Z\right|\gt t\right)\leqslant u\right\}. $$
Rio's covariance inequality [1] states that for two random variables 
$X$ and $Y$, $$\left|\operatorname{Cov}\left(X,Y\right)\right|\leqslant 2\int_0^{\alpha\left(X,Y\right)} Q_X(u)Q_Y(u)\mathrm du.  
  $$
In your context, observe that for $t\gt 0$, $\mathbb P\left(|Z|\gt t\right)\leqslant 1-\mathbb P\left(Z=0\right)$ hence $Q_Z\left(u\right)=0$ if $u\geqslant 1-\mathbb P\left(Z=0\right)$. Moreover, $Q_Z(u)\leqslant \lVert Z\rVert_\infty$, hence 
$$\left|\operatorname{Cov}\left(X,Y\right)\right|\leqslant 2\alpha
(X,Y) \min\left\{1-\mathbb P\left(X=0\right),1-\mathbb P\left(X=0\right)\right\}\lVert X\rVert_\infty\lVert Y\rVert_\infty.$$

[1]
Rio, Emmanuel. "Covariance inequalities for strongly mixing processes." Annales de l'I.H.P. Probabilités et statistiques 29.4 (1993): 587-597. http://eudml.org/doc/77471.